# Set logging leel for akka event bus compilation error

Tags: java, spring, akka

I'm trying to write a JMX bean which could change the current logging level for all of the akka actors like this:

```
@ManagedResource(objectName = "com.company:name=LoggingLevelHandler")
public class LoggingLevelHandlerJmxBean {

@Autowired
private ActorSystem system;

@ManagedOperation(description = "Change logging level of the application")
public boolean changeLogLevel(String newLevel) {
    EventStream currentStream = system.eventStream();
    currentStream.setLogLevel(Logging.levelFor(newLevel).get());
    return true;
}

private akka.event.Logging.LogLevel getLevelForName(String name){
    switch(name) {
        case("ERROR"):{
            return Logging.ErrorLevel();
        }
        case("WARN"):{
            return Logging.WarningLevel();
        }
        case("INFO"):{
            return Logging.InfoLevel();
        }
        case("DEBUG"):{
            return Logging.DebugLevel();
        }
    }
    return akka.event.Logging.InfoLevel();
}
}
```

I got an error `Error:(31, 69) java: incompatible types: akka.event.Logging.LogLevel cannot be converted to int` in the string:

```
currentStream.setLogLevel(Logging.levelFor(newLevel).get());
```

When I change it into `currentStream.setLogLevel(Logging.InfoLevel())` this error disappears. But when I tried to use a custom function getLevelForName (just for experiment) it appeared again. And `currentStream.setLogLevel(Logging.levelFor("error").get())` leads to the same compilation error. Seems like any additional return (or return address in the top of VM stack ?) leads to the error.

Javac: 1.8.0_91

akka: 2.4.4

build system: maven 3.3.9

Thanks for any help

Cheers, Alexey